# Make qhull/qvoronoi limit Voronoi to convex hull or given polygon

Tags: qhull

A planar Voronoi tesselation will always have unbounded polygons 
(infinite regions).

How do I tell qhull/qvoronoi to intersect the tesselation with either 
the original points' convex hull, or with a polygon I explicitly 
specify (probably a rectangle).

Specific example ( https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-temperature-voronoi.pl ):

- I map latitudes/longitudes (inaccurately) to the 2-D rectangle 
  (-180,180)*(-90,90), and apply qvoronoi to the result.
- I can't handle unbounded polygons and Google Maps API dislikes 
  polygons that wander outside (-180,180)*(-90,90) [actually, it's more like (-180,180)*(-85,85) because Google uses Mercator]
- Can I make qhull/qvoronoi intersect the polygons with the points' 
  convex hull and/or the (-180,180)*(-90,90) rectangle? Of course, the 
  convex hull is entirely contained within the rectangle.
- If not, can another program do it? I suspect I could write this 
  myself, but would prefer an existing solution.

Comment: I would like to know this too